# Locating specific items in an array

Tags: arrays, sorting, variables, compare

as a mindless beginner in PHP/HTML I want to create an array called WHEEL with 36 numbers in the specific sequence:

0   32  15  19  4   21  2   25  17  34  6   27  13  36  11  30  8   23  10  5   24  16  33  1   20  14  31  9   22  18  29  7   28  12  35  3   26

Another variable called NUMBER states for example 5

Now I want to locate in WHEEL number 5 and its neighbors 10 and 24 and write each of those numbers into a separate variable.

Sounds pritty darn - however, would appreciate some hints from you.

Thanks
Klaus from overheated Germany ....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here code implementation of your problem

```html
<?php
$wheels = [0, 32, 15, 19, 4, 21, 2, 25, 17, 34, 6, 27, 13, 36, 11, 30, 8, 23, 10, 5, 24, 16, 33, 1, 20, 14, 31, 9, 22, 18, 29, 7, 28, 12, 35, 3, 26];

$number = 5

$numberPosition = array_search($number,$wheels); // it returns index of array element false if not exist
$leftNeighbor = ($numberPosition) ? $wheels[$numberPosition-1] : false; // substracted -1 from position to get left element
$rightNeighbor = ($numberPosition) ? $wheels[$numberPosition+1] : false; // added +1 from position to get right element

?>
```

Comment: Thanks so much Dev for your smart solution. I would have written some aweful lot of "if - else "stuff that would not work in the end. This brings me foreward ...